# How can I monitor/locate specific communications between programs on WIN10?

Tags: service, message-queue, communication

**Background information**: I use a Scientific Program that collects data and writes it to a .raw format file. In this program is an option to launch an .exe file to perform post processing once the .raw file is finished writing. I created a .exe file to run that will to post process to my needs, however, this post processing feature of the program is no longer supported/broken.

I'm not quite sure how to figure out what communications are being done by the program to "finish writing .raw file". Once I figure out this communication, I'm planning to convert the .exe to a service to look for that communication so it can perform the post processing once the .raw file is finished writing.

I believe the information is being shared through the MessageQueueingService (MSMQ) on WIN10 but I'm not quite sure how to access that information. I would really like to see all communications in a 15 second Window to find this.

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!